# For what $x$ values does the integral have a minimum

Tags: calculus, integration

### Question

> [image]

### My Understanding

I'm really confused because I flipped the function to solve it (turned the integral negative and made lower value upper value...) and I got $2$ as the answer, but when I checked it, it was wrong. I know it can't be $0$ either. So it's $-2$? Or can there be multiple minimum points? Because $-2$ is a minimum when we don't flip the function. But $2$ is the minimum when we flip it. I'm really confused.

Comment: That seems to be graph of $2 \cos \frac {\pi \ t}{4}$. The integral will be min at $x = 2$ or for that matter $8n+2$ in general should work.

Comment: Sorry I just edited the post. I meant to say that I got 2 initially but that was wrong. So it's either -2 or both 2 & -2. But I thought there can only be 1 minimum and 2 is only in the interval when I flip the function so I'm not sure if that's right either. Also it's not 0 because my instructor said so.

Comment: I just deleted my previous comment, which was based on the *mistaken* idea that $g(x)$ intersects the $x$-axis at $(x=1)$, rather than $(x=2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the problem was changed to minimizing $h(x) = \int_x^2 g(t)dt$ and further suppose that you were (temporarily) only considering values of $x$ such that $x < 1$.  It is clear that

1. $h(-6) = 0$.
2. Because of the symmetry around $g(t)$, and because the graph of $g(t)$ for the area between $(-2 \leq t \leq 2)$ is completely positive, it is clear that there is no value for $x < 1$ such that $h(x) < 0.$

Furthermore, when $x$ is constrained to $x < 1$, minimizing $f(x)$ is equivalent to minimizing $h(x)$.  That is, $f(x)$ will have a minimum at $(x = x_0 < 1) \iff h(x)$ is similarly minimized at $(x = x_0 < 1).$

Consequently, the problem is reduced to considering only those values of $x$ such that $x > 1$.  Further, values of $x$ such that $1 \leq x \leq 2$ can be considered at the end of this answer.

Given that, it is clear that minimizing $f(x)$ for $x > 2$ is (again) similar to minimizing $h(x)$ for $x > 2$.  Therefore,  the following considerations apply, when $x>2$.

3. $\int_x^2 g(t)dt = -\int_2^x g(t)dt.$
4. The graph of $g(t)$ for the region $2 \leq x \leq 6$ is completely negative.

Therefore, it is immediate that for $x > 2$, the minimum achievable value for $h(x)$ will be $0 = h(10) = -\int_2^{10} g(t)dt.$

Consider $\int_2^1 g(t)dt = -\int_ 1^2 g(t)dt < 0$.

You can see by the symmetry of the graph of $g(t)$, that just as $h(-6) = h(2) = h(10),~f(-6) = f(2) = f(10).$

Answer (score 0):

If we let $G^\prime(x)=g(x)$ then we have $f(x)=G(1)-G(x)$. Then $f^\prime(x)=-G^\prime(x)=-g(x)$.

We know that $f$ will have a minimum value at the value $x_0$ where $f^\prime(x_0)=0$ and where $f^\prime(x)<0$ on some interval $(a,x_0)$ and $f^\prime(x)>0$ on some interval $(x_0,b)$. This is because $f$ will be decreasing to the left of $x_0$ and increasing to the right of $x_0$.

Since $f^\prime(x)=-g(x)$ you can find $x_0$ by inspecting the graph of $y=-g(x)$.

Turn the graph of $g$ "upside down" and we see that the conditions are met for $x_0=2$.

Comment: First off, thank you. Secondly, I'm still a bit confused. Would 2 still be in the interval even though we flipped the function (i.e. set the integral to negative and switched the lower/upper values)? That's where I'm really stuck. Because I'm literally changing the interval so would it still be an answer? Sorry if it's a silly question or something you already addressed

Comment: You seem to be focusing on the wrong thing. It is not a matter of shuffling things around in the integral. When trying to find where the minimum of the function occurs you should be looking for where the function is decreasing, then increasing. That is, where $f^\prime(x)<0$ and where $f^\prime(x)>0$. So it is important to discover that $f^\prime(x)=-g(x)$ since you are given the graph of $g(x)$.